# Unpacking numpy using ndarray

Tags: python, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I'm new to python. Any help would be appreciated.

I want to [show this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gteAJ.png)
, using the first block of codes which I have tried, but when I try to run this code:

```
date, value = np.loadtxt(revenue_ar, delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={ 0: bytespdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})
```

using [revenue_ar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHUuR.png) (numpy.ndarray) this error message pops up:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

First block of codes:

```
import time
import requests
import intrinio
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    

api_username = 'hidden'
api_password = 'hidden'

def bytespdate2num(fmt, encoding='utf-8'):
    strconverter = mdates.strpdate2num(fmt)
    def bytesconverter(b):
        s = b.decode(encoding)
        return strconverter(s)
    return bytesconverter

ticker = 'AAPL' 
revenue_data = requests.get('https://api.intrinio.com/historical_data?identifier=' + ticker + '&item=totalrevenue', auth=(api_username, api_password))
revenue1 = revenue_data.json()['data'] 
revenue = pd.DataFrame(revenue1) 
revenue_ar = revenue.values

date, value = np.loadtxt(revenue_ar, delimiter=',', unpack=True,
                                   converters={ 0: bytespdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})('%Y-%m-%d')})('%Y-%m-%d')})

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,4), (0,0), rowspan=6, colspan=4)
ax1.plot(date,value)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.show()
```

However, This seems to work using [revenue.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwpHu.png):

```
date, value = np.loadtxt('revenue.txt', delimiter='\t', unpack=True,
                                   converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y-%m-%d')})
```

Please let me know if I need to clarify my question further.
Thanks in advance.

---

revenue1:

```
[{'date': '2018-03-31', 'value': 247417000000.0},
{'date': '2017-12-30', 'value': 239176000000.0},
{'date': '2017-09-30', 'value': 229234000000.0},
{'date': '2017-07-01', 'value': 223507000000.0},
{'date': '2017-04-01', 'value': 220457000000.0},
{'date': '2016-12-31', 'value': 218118000000.0},
{'date': '2016-09-24', 'value': 215639000000.0},
{'date': '2016-06-25', 'value': 220288000000.0},
{'date': '2016-03-26', 'value': 227535000000.0},
{'date': '2015-12-26', 'value': 234988000000.0},
{'date': '2015-09-26', 'value': 233715000000.0},
{'date': '2015-06-27', 'value': 224337000000.0},
{'date': '2015-03-28', 'value': 212164000000.0},
```

revenue_ar:

```
array([['2018-03-31', 247417000000.0],
       ['2017-12-30', 239176000000.0],
       ['2017-09-30', 229234000000.0],
       ['2017-07-01', 223507000000.0],
       ['2017-04-01', 220457000000.0],
       ['2016-12-31', 218118000000.0],
       ['2016-09-24', 215639000000.0],
       ['2016-06-25', 220288000000.0],
       ['2016-03-26', 227535000000.0],
       ['2015-12-26', 234988000000.0],
       ['2015-09-26', 233715000000.0],
```

revenue.txt:

```
2007-09-29  2.457800e+10
2008-09-27  3.749100e+10
2009-09-26  4.290500e+10
2009-12-26  4.670800e+10
2010-03-27  5.112300e+10
2010-06-26  5.708900e+10
2010-09-25  6.522500e+10
2010-12-25  7.628300e+10
2011-03-26  8.745100e+10
2011-06-25  1.003220e+11
2011-09-24  1.082490e+11
```

---

This would be the solution as you have suggested.
This is awesome as it runs smoothly.

```
import time
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
import intrinio
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime

api_username = 'hidden'
api_password = 'hidden'

def grab_intrinio(ticker):
    try:
        revenue_data = requests.get('https://api.intrinio.com/historical_data?    identifier=' + ticker + '&item=totalrevenue', auth=(api_username, api_password))
        revenue1 = revenue_data.json()['data'] 
        revenue = pd.DataFrame(revenue1)
        revenue['date'] = pd.to_datetime(revenue['date'])

        plt.plot(revenue['date'], revenue['value'])

    except Exception as e:
        print('failed in the main loop',str(e))
        pass

grab_intrinio('AAPL')
```

This produce output as:

[image: revenue graph]

**I have 2 more things to work on. 
First, I want to graph two more variables(net_income and roe)

Second, my roe data has an value of nm which can not be converted to float or integer.

How could I resolve this problem?**

As a final output, I want to show a graph like this one(I can do my own work on plots and details of configuration):

[image: final graph]

I have tried this line, but this doesn't seem to work with an error showing `'list' object has no attribute 'plot'.`

```
fig = plt.figure()

    ax1 = plt.plot(net_income['date'], net_income['value'])
    ax1.plot(net_income['date'], net_income['value'])

    ax2 = plt.plot(revenue['date'], revenue['value'])
    ax2.plot(revenue['date'], revenue['value'])
```

This one produces net_income and revenue in same plot:

```
plt.plot(net_income['date'], net_income['value'])
plt.plot(revenue['date'], revenue['value'])
```

[image]

> Blockquote

Here are the codes for net_income and roe(same format as revenue)

```
net_income_data = requests.get('https://api.intrinio.com/historical_data?identifier=' + ticker + '&item=totalrevenue', auth=(api_username, api_password))
net_income1 = net_income_data.json()['data']
net_income = pd.DataFrame(net_income1)
net_income['date'] = pd.to_datetime(net_income['date'])        

roe_data = requests.get('https://api.intrinio.com/historical_data?identifier=' + ticker + '&item=roe', auth=(api_username, api_password))
roe1 = roe_data.json()['data']
roe = pd.DataFrame(roe1)
roe['date'] = pd.to_datetime(revenue['date'])
```

This is a roe_date with `nm value`

```
    date    value
30  2010-09-25  0.352835
31  2010-06-26  0.354701
32  2010-03-27  0.274779
33  2009-12-26  0.261631
34  2009-09-26  0.305356
35  2008-09-27  0.274432
36  2007-09-29  nm
```

Here is the results for the `roe.dtypes`

```
In: roe.dtypes
Out: date     datetime64[ns]
     value            object
     dtype: object
```

Whereas, both `net_income.dtypes` and `revenue.dtypes` produce output as follows:

```
In: net_income.dtypes(revenue.dtypes)
Out: date     datetime64[ns]
     value           float64
     dtype: object
```

---

Your amendment on roe to convert from object to float worked to plot the graph. When I aggregate the function as a final step, I'm getting an `invalid syntax` error as the following:

```
File "<ipython-input-141-537d7c6c91a3>", line 28
    fig axs = plt.subplots(3)
```

For this function written with your assistance.

```
def grab_intrinio(ticker):
    try:
        net_income_data = requests.get('https://api.intrinio.com/historical_data?identifier=' + ticker + '&item=netincome', auth=(api_username, api_password)) # 
        net_income1 = net_income_data.json()['data']
        net_income = pd.DataFrame(net_income1)
        net_income['date'] = pd.to_datetime(net_income['date'])

        revenue_data = requests.get('https://api.intrinio.com/historical_data?identifier=' + ticker + '&item=totalrevenue', auth=(api_username, api_password))
        revenue1 = revenue_data.json()['data']
        revenue = pd.DataFrame(revenue1)

        revenue['date'] = pd.to_datetime(revenue['date'])
        revenue

        roe_data = requests.get('https://api.intrinio.com/historical_data?identifier=' + ticker + '&item=roe', auth=(api_username, api_password))
        roe1 = roe_data.json()['data']
        roe = pd.DataFrame(roe1)
        roe['date'] = pd.to_datetime(roe['date'])
        roe.index = roe['date']
        roe = roe.drop(columns=['date'])
        nm_idx = roe['value'] =='nm'

        roe.value[nm_idx] = np.nan
        roe.value = roe.value.astype(float)

        fig axs = plt.subplots(3)
        for ax, dat in zip(axs, [net_income, Revenue, roc]):
            ax.plot(dat['date'], dat['value'])

    except exception as e:
        print('failed in the main loop',str(e))
        pass

grab_intrinio('AAPL')
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Ok, `if I add this line, I get the following error: #*KeyError: 'date'` understood, but look at the error message: is it really this line, which throws the error or does this line work and later you try to access the date-column - which throws this error because it was successfully dropped before?

Comment: Sorry, I am still new at python So, it takes some time for me to revisit the question and answer. I have edited my question and by omitting this line' df = df.drop(columns=['date']) ' all seems to run smoothly.

Comment: How could I address the problem of roe data that has value nm that can not be converted to either string or integer?

Comment: thanks for removing the images of data.            is roe successfully put into a dataframe? could you post the result of `roe.dtypes` then?

Comment: `This would be the solution as you have suggested. This is awesome as it runs smoothly` - how can that run smoothly, because you read your data in the variable `revenue`, but for plotting, you suddenly use `df`: `plt.plot(df['date'], df['value'])` I'd expect an error here.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I was trying to replicate your code in my own variables. Your code using my own variable works well. I edited my codes. Also, I provided the output of roe.dtypes.

Answer (score 0):

`np.loadtxt` expects a filename or a string variable, from which it can parse the data out. That's why it works by telling it a path but not by telling it an array of values.

So you obviously get valid json data via `requests.get` and decode it via

```
revenue1 = revenue_data.json()['data']
```

and put it in a dataframe with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(revenue1)
```

This is what it looks like:

```
In: df.head()
Out: 
         date         value
0  2018-01-31  247417000000
1  2017-12-30  239176000000
2  2017-09-30  229234000000
3  2017-07-01  223507000000
```

and this is how to check the data types of the columns in your dataframe:

```
In: df.dtypes
Out: 
date     object
value     int64
dtype: object
```

`value` is an integer, which is nice, but `date` was not parsed, it's just object data, so let's fix this:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

In: df
Out: 
        date         value
0 2018-01-31  247417000000
1 2017-12-30  239176000000
2 2017-09-30  229234000000
3 2017-07-01  223507000000

In: df.dtypes
Out: 
date     datetime64[ns]
value             int64
dtype: object    df = df.drop(columns=['date'])
```

Now `date` has the right datatype and you could plot it like

```
plt.plot(df['date'], df['value'])
```

[image]

However, you could make it even more convenient, if you put the date as your index:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.drop(columns=['date'])
```

Because the you could simply call

```
df.plot()
```

as pandas has a matplotlib interface on board.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

For  your triple plot you'd need sth like:

```
fig axs = plt.subplots(3)
for ax, dat in zip(axs, [net_income, Revenue, roc]):
    ax.plot(dat['date'], dat['value'])
```

---

Some of your data can't be cast to float because of `nm`-entries. Replace them by `np.nan` so that plotting commands can handle it and you can use your data:

```
In: roe
Out: 
          date     value
30  2010-09-25  0.352835
31  2010-06-26  0.354701
32  2010-03-27  0.274779
33  2009-12-26  0.261631
34  2009-09-26  0.305356
35  2008-09-27  0.274432
36  2007-09-29        nm

roe.index = roe['date']
roe = roe.drop(columns=['date'])
nm_idx = roe['value'] =='nm'

roe.value[nm_idx] = np.nan
roe.value = roe.value.astype(float)

In: roe
Out: 
               value
date                
2010-09-25  0.352835
2010-06-26  0.354701
2010-03-27  0.274779
2009-12-26  0.261631
2009-09-26  0.305356
2008-09-27  0.274432
2007-09-29       NaN

In: roe.dtypes
Out: 
value    float64
dtype: object
```

roe.plot()

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comments. your solution returns error message of: could not convert string to float: '2007-09-29'.  I have provided samples of revenue_ar and revenue.txt in the above question. You can check them out by clicking the each word. Cheers,

Comment: Ah, I didn' t notice that your data has dates as x-values. At first, let me mention that you please shall not post code nor text file content/samples as images. This just not nice to those people who want to help you, because nothing is copy/pastable for testing or to check what's going wrong. For lists or arrays you can simply post the output of `my_list[:5]` or for a dataframe there is the nice little function `df.head()`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Do you have a better idea to resolve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I just have no computer access at the moment, just mobile phone. But I'll edit...

Comment: Thanks for the edited comments. However, when I try    df = pd.read_json(revenue_data), the following error message is shown:   ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'requests.models.Response'>

Comment: Again, please post computable samples of your data, not images. And please post a sample of revenue_data. However, I'll edit to Show how to proceed without the json-decoder of pandas...